# xcode: print MKMapView region, span, latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, mkmapview

I am trying to NSLog the region, span, latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta of MKMapView. But it sends message like

```
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
```

My code is like this:

```
@interface TaetPaViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, NSXMLParserDelegate> {
    IBOutlet MKMapView *regionsMapView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *regionsMapView;

@synthesize regionsMapView;

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated{
    NSLog(@"regionsMapView.region.span.latitudeDelta: %@", regionsMapView.region.span.latitudeDelta);

}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [regionsMapView release];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you-re printing double (`latitudeDelta`) as a pointer. Use `%f` instead or something similar